# Android launcher

Tags: android, android-activity, launch

I need to start android application not with Activity^ but with some controller class that will start some activity

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but an Android application is built up by four "components" as mentioned in the "Android Application Fundamentals", http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html (no, you don't need all four of them make your application work).

The most common way of starting an application (and actually the only one I've been in touch with) is to define an Activity in your applications AndroidManifest.xml file as described on the link above. NOTE! that an Activity doesn't have to define a UI; you are not obligated to call the "setContentView()" function. Hence your "controller class" can extend Activity and be the very Activity you define as the start-up Activity in your manifest xml. You can then call "startActivity()" function with parameters to start any other Activity, whenever you see fit, from your controller class (this is also described in the link above).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Either create a GUI-less activity without calling `setContentView()` or use a BroadcastReceiver that accepts launcher intents (action=MAIN, cateogry=LAUNCHER). In Activity.onCreate or receivers callback method you can place logic which will invoke the actual activity of choice.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the BroadcastReceiver. I totally forgot about that one :-)